# Javascript and Dvorak: Is there a way to get the key pressed rather than the character?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to make a webapp with hotkeys that work the same for all keyboard layouts.  I've done it before with other languages, but I haven't been able to find a way with Javascript.  I can only get the character of the key that was pressed, not the key independent of keyboard layout.

In the [MDN Doc for "keydown"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown), keycode looked promising, but it was not.

Is there a way to get the key pressed rather than the character?

The best solution I can think of without this is a user layout translation option hidden somewhere in settings, which is fine too.

Comment: I don't understand why you need this; how does the user know which key to press if the key is independent of the character on the key?

Comment: ctr-z is a common example of this.  Just because your layout has some other letter where z normally is does not mean you want that to be your hotkey.

Comment: but in this case, I'm using the keyboard as a piano and I personally use an alt layout, but I'd like to code for myself and QWERTY users at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to retrieve this information directly from browser APIs. One possibility would be to use a plugin like [Layoutline](https://github.com/ahtcx/layoutline) ([demo](https://ahtcx.github.io/layoutline/)) which could be a prerequisite step for users of your application.